# Finitely Presented Infinite Group has an Element of Infinite Order?

Tags: group-theory

Is it true that an infinite group which is finitely generated must have an element of infinite order? If not, I'd like a counterexample.

[Edit] 
Somewhat easily proven false.

More interesting (and as it happens, more relevant to my particular problem domain), what about finitely presented groups?

Comment: There are infinite Burnside groups.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_problem

Comment: See also the [Grigorchuk group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigorchuk_group) for a standard counterexample to many similar questions.

Comment: It is true for *abelian* groups.

Comment: More interesting to ask this question for *finitely presented* groups.

Comment: (Someone should wrap all these comments into an answer...)

Comment: @SteveD this should be my question, and had I thought more about it before asking, it would have been. Are you implying the problem is open?

Comment: The Tarski monster groups deserve a mention - they are finitely generated groups such that every people, non-trivial subgroup is cyclic of order a fixed prime $p$. These exist for all primes greater than some number which has been calculated by I cannot recall of the top of my head. They were first proven to exist by Ol'shanskii in the early 80s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In full generality, this is false.  As mentioned in the comments, the [Burnside groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_problem#Bounded_Burnside_problem) can be infinite groups, finitely generated by construction, such that every element has bounded finite order. One can even force such a group to be simple.

There are positive results for certain families of groups, however.  Immediately I am reminded of solvable groups and hyperbolic groups.

Perhaps a much more interesting question is if there is a *finitely presented*, infinite group, with no element of infinite order.  AFAIK, this question is still wide open.